# Symfony 2.7 choice callback not working in form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a class with a multiple choice property:

```
...

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array", name="majority_types")
 * @Constraints\Choice(callback="getAvailableMajorityTypes", multiple="true")
 */
private $majorityTypes;

...

public static function getAvailableMajorityTypes()
{
    return array(
        self::SIMPLE_MAJORITY,
        self::UNANIMITY_MAJORITY,
        self::THREE_FIFTHS_MAJORITY,
        self::ONE_THIRD_MAJORITY,
        self::FOUR_FIFTHS_MAJORITY
    );
}

...
```

I also have a form class for this class:

```
...

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ...
        ->add('majorityTypes', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'multiple' => true,
        ))
        ...
        ->getForm();
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'MyClass',
    ));
}
```

But the choices from `getAvailableMajorityTypes` are not rendered.

I simply followed these steps: http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/constraints/Choice.html#supplying-the-choices-with-a-callback-function, but for some reason it doesn't work.

**Edit:**

I see that using static choices as annotations neither works (`choices={"foo1", "foo2"}`). The only way it works is passing the choices directly in the `add` method when creating the form. I've not found out the problem yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I refer to your words:

> But the choices from `getAvailableMajorityTypes` are not rendered.

It seems you're confused between rendering of options in your form's select field and the `Choice` constraint.

You've only implemented the constraint in your code, but you also need to add the options to your select. Like this:

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ...
        ->add('majorityTypes', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'multiple' => true,
            'choices' => YourEntity::getAvailableMajorityTypes()
        ))
```

Comment: From the last part of the question: *The only way it works is passing the choices directly in the add method when creating the form*. This is what you are suggesting. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes indeed. The other things you tried are related to validation of the submitted form, not the rendering of the html form.

Comment: It makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this annotation, however in the documentation the callback is public static:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Author.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class Author
{
    public static function getGenders()
    {
        return array('male', 'female');
    }
}
```

If you follow the documentation and make your method static as well the annotation should work.

Comment: Yes, it was a cluelessness. Anyway, it still doesn't work. It seems that the callback is never called, as if I rename the callback to an non-existent method, no error is thrown.